# Dealing with Multiple Coloumn Variable List

Tags: batch-file

I am having a list of variable which is 50 (a notepad file, XYZ_List.txt), but the variable list is in three column (i.e- 004852 (space) E (space) STK@6.0) which is system generated, but I want to execute the below mentioned loop (task) with the Column no.-(1) or (3), how could I perform the same?

`for /f %%I in (C:\XYZ_List.txt) do run -i -D %%I`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%I in (C:\XYZ_List.txt) do echo I=%%I  J=%%J  K=%%K
```

should show `I=004852 J=E K=STK@6.0`

Resources:

- `FOR /F` [Loop command: parse the contents of a file](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [valid delimiters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: Thanks Josef for your reply. `for /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%I in (C:\XYZ_List.txt) do run -i -D %%I`

Comment: Is there any way to make display the only specific column (entire) by `echo`, or something else ?

Comment: @ShankarMajumder you can `echo` whatever you want. Honestly said, I don't understand your additional demand. Please elaborate it, preferably in another question.